# Strong monics in the category of locales

Tags: ct.category-theory, locales

Are there non-regular strong monics in the category of locales?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  The category of locales is dual to the category of frames, which is monadic (in fact, equationally presented) over Set.  Any such category is Barr-exact, and in particular a regular category, which implies that every strong epic of frames is regular—hence every strong monic of locales is regular.

Comment: Yep.  Just found it myself in Sketches of an Elephant A.1.3.4.  Thank you, though!